# JAVA What happen if I schedule my timertask everyday at 12:00 PM after that time?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I'm using the following code to schedule a timer (java.util.Timer):

```
Timer mytimer = new Timer("My Timer");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
mytimer.schedule(mytask, c.getTime(), 24*60*60*1000);
```

I want the timer task to run everyday at 12:00 PM.
My question is what will happen if the application is running AFTER 12:00. Let's say 16:00. Will the timer task run the next day at 12:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the Timer Class states the following about the method [**public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long))

> In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well. In the long run, the frequency of execution will generally be slightly lower than the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate). As a consequence of the above, **if the scheduled first time is in the past, it is scheduled for immediate execution**.

So we can understand from the above that the task will immediately be scheduled and executed and after that according to your program will be executed 24 hours later again. So if it is 16:00 then it will the executed immediately and will again be executed at 16:00 the next day.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I've missed that!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that? I scheduled one job to run only once a day, to send alert notifications among team. Problem is, sometimes I have to restart application for deployment, in that case, team gets notifications multiple times a day. I don't want that. Could you please help

Comment: @theGamblerRises why don't you post your question as a new question giving the details of the problem and the scenario in which the problem is occurring. Then we could help you out with the same. A question in the comment is not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), as

> It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the
>   Timer/TimerTask combination 
>   [(link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Also, Java 8 provides some useful tools to make the required time calculations. An example could be:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void schedule(Runnable command) {
    LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    LocalDateTime executionDate = LocalDateTime.of(currentTime.getYear(), 
                                                   currentTime.getMonth(), 
                                                   currentTime.getDayOfMonth(), 
                                                   12, 0); // begin execution at 12:00 AM

    long initialDelay;

    if(currentTime.isAfter(executionDate)){
        // take the next day, if we passed the execution date
        initialDelay = currentTime.until(executionDate.plusDays(1), ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    } else {
        initialDelay = currentTime.until(executionDate, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    }

    long delay = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24); // repeat after 24 hours

    ScheduledFuture<?> x = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(command, initialDelay, delay , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: I can't use Java 8, so unfortunately it's not the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a time 11:59 PM then your issue will be resolve.
it call because 12:00 PM date will be change so it will call your task.
so change a time 12:00 PM to 11:59

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for the answer to the same question and I have come up with a possible solution. Keeping in mind that I'm a total newbie and may be committing many programming crimes by doing this.

If your timer is running anyway why not just check for a specific time like this:

```
if(date.compareTo("00:00:00") == 0){
    //TODO
}
```